# Prevent GNOME from expanding windows

Tags: gnome

When I click on a GNOME window's title bar and drag it to the top of the screen and let go, GNOME expands the window to be full-screen. I don't like this---I just want the window at the top of my screen. Is there any way to stop this annoying behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can turn off edge tiling using:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides edge-tiling false
```

Comment: Didn't work for me on Ubuntu 17.10, however the solution  proposed by @protoEvangelion did work.

Answer (score 3):

I stopped inflicting Gnome on myself a long time ago, so I haven't tried it myself, but I did find [this](http://www.downfromthetrees.com/2012/07/stop-window-auto-maximize-in-gnome-3.html), whose relevant parts are:

> - You need dconf-editor. Install it per your distribution's recommendations. I'm running Fedora 17 at the moment and this is the command line incantation I used: sudo yum install dconf-editor.
> - Launch dconf-editor. On the left you will see a simple menu with five entries. Click on the plus sign to the left of org. New menu entires will drop down beneath it. Click on the plus sign to the left of gnome. Scroll down, then click on the plus sign to the left of mutter.
> - Click on mutter next to the plus sign to highlight it. Several entries will appear in the large window to the right.
>     If the edge-tiling entry is checked, click it to uncheck it. If it is already unchecked, leave it unchecked.
> - Scroll down the left panel and click on the plus sign to the left of shell.
> - Go to the overrides entry below shell and click on it.
> - Again, you are looking for the edge-tiling entry in the right window. Make sure it is not checked.
> - Close dconf-editor.
>
> Note: This turns off all edge-tiling. The Gnome Shell effect that snaps a window to the left or right side of the screen and opens it to one-half screenwidth will not work after disabling edge-tiling. If you decide to get it back, return to dconf-editor and re-enable it.

Comment: Thanks. That's a lot. What do you use instead of GNOME?

Comment: Windows, mostly. :) But on my Linux workstation, I greatly prefer KDE; while it has its points of suckage, on average I find it much less obstreperous than Gnome ever was, and more flexible and easily configurable besides. (For example, I don't have root on this box, and while I can change the monitor position and orientation via nvidia-settings at will, I can't modify the default X config to set them there, so must apply the change on each login. I couldn't find a way to make Gnome notice those changes once applied; with KDE I just `kill -HUP` kicker, kdesktop, and kwin, and I'm good to go.)

Answer (score 3):

If the other solutions **do not** work for you, try:

`dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/edge-tiling false`

I tried several commands, but this was the only command that worked for me on **Ubuntu 17.10**

Here is the resource that led me to this solution if you are curious:

http://strugglers.net/~andy/blog/2017/12/14/disabling-edge-tiling-on-gnome-3-26/

Answer (score 1):

The first answer did not work for me, but since it was from 2013, I understand.  I am here in August 2021, and it did lead me to what does work. I run a CentOS-7.4 Linux box, with a 5.4.101-1.el17.elrepo.x86_64 kernel (from Feb. 26, 2021).  This Linux box runs very good, nice and stable - it's my mission-critical "daily-driver".  To get Gnome to stop the edge-moved-Window maximize, I finally figured out that this "gsettings" string will work:

gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.classic-overrides edge-tiling false

You don't need root privilages to run this, just run the command in any xterm window. It appears to update dconf correctly, and the annoying auto-maximizing window "feature" is prevented. (If working with many windows open, a typical use-case is wanting the ability to just push them around like papers and books on your desk.  Auto-edge-maximize-window prevents this.)

Comment: Welcome to August 2021 from May 2013. Got any tips for us back here in the past?